# Does the refresh token have to be a random string?

Tags: jwt

On some sites who use jwt and refresh token, I noticed that refresh token is just a random string of 25 or more characters, now I have a question: can a refresh token be generated in the same way as access, that is, through the jwt library? Then it will not be just a random string, but a token with payload, etc., and it will be easier to validate.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need anything beyond a random string for the refresh token. You only need to look it up in the authorization server and there is not need for some more magic feature than that. Keeping it simple. The client receiving the refresh token does not need to validate it either.